# when closing the qt application, want to kill qprocess

Tags: c++, qt

in my mainwindow.cpp, inside the constructor, I started a qprocess so the process(.exe) runs when I open the qt application.

Now I want to kill/close the qprocess when I close the qt application. How can I do it?

Comment: Best practice would be to send the second process a message asking it to politely and safely shut down as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for `QProcess::terminate` and `QProcess::kill`. They each have slightly different behavior. Use `terminate` to give the process a chance to shut down gracefully. Use `kill` to kill it more forcefully. In the case of `terminate`, you probably want to wait until the child process has finished (e.g. `QProcess::waitForFinished`) before exiting the parent process.